# Why does this statement(Jtime time1 = Jtime(1,2,4);) only call the constructor once

Tags: c++

**As I understand it(Jtime time1 = Jtime(1,2,4);), shouldn't the left and right sides of this statement call the constructor once**

```
class Jtime
{
public:
    Jtime(){ std::cout << "No argument constructor"; }
    Jtime(double h, double M, double S)
    {
        std::cout << "There is a parameter constructor H M S";
        Hours_ = h; Minte_ = M; Sencon_ = S;
    }

    ~Jtime() = default;

private:
    double Hours_;
    double Minte_;
    double Sencon_;

};
int main()
{
    Jtime time1 = Jtime(1,2,4);
}
```

Comment: No. The copy constructor will be called, which is implicitly defined in your class.

Comment: Nope.  Sematically, it initialises a temporary (unnamed) object as `JTime(1,2,4)` and then uses the copy constructor to initialise `time1`.     Your code is not tracking calls of the copy constructor.   Furthermore, there are specific rules that allow (and, in C++11 and later, require) the compiler to elide temporaries in several sircumstances (i.e. cause them not to exist, and therefore not to be copied) - so it is possible that there will only be one call of any constructor.

Comment: Read up on [Copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @Peter: Required copy elision happens only since C++17

Comment: @JesperJuhlj  appreciate